# Prestashop_8.1.1 local installation issue

Tags: prestashop

I'm try to install the package on my computer with Wamp (PHP 8.2.0)
The installation stops at last step (creation of parameter files, at 0%) with http Error 500
Please help me!

I tried to downgrade the PHP version but I had error message at the step 'system compatibility' then I upgrede to PHP 8.2 again, I modified php.ini with uncomment and modify line `realpath_cache_size = 5M`

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 0):

PrestaShop 8.1 is not compatible with PHP 8.2 You have all system requirements listed here:
https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/8/basics/installation/system-requirements/